# javascript websocket connect to QWebSocketServer failed

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, websocket, qtnetwork

I'm using QWebSocketServer to provide communication with javascript websocket.

The code is very similar with EchoServer in Qt Examples.

javascript side code is listed as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function WebSocketTest()
{
  if ("WebSocket" in window)
  {
     //alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
     // Let us open a web socket
     var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:12345");
     ws.onopen = function()
     {
        // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
        ws.send("Message to send");
        alert("Message is sent...");
     };
     ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
     { 
        var received_msg = evt.data;
        alert("Message is received...");
     };
     ws.onclose = function()
     { 
        // websocket is closed.
        alert("Connection is closed..."); 
     };

     ws.onerror = function(error){
        console.log('Error detected: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
     }

  }
  else
  {
     // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
     alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sse">
   <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I get this error:

```
Error detected: {"path":{"length":0},"cancelBubble":false,"returnValue":true,"srcElement":{"binaryType":"blob","extensions":"","protocol":"","bufferedAmount":0,"readyState":3,"url":"ws://localhost:12345/","URL":"ws://localhost:12345/"},"defaultPrevented":false,"timeStamp":1408698611478,"cancelable":false,"bubbles":false,"eventPhase":2,"currentTarget":{"binaryType":"blob","extensions":"","protocol":"","bufferedAmount":0,"readyState":3,"url":"ws://localhost:12345/","URL":"ws://localhost:12345/"},"target":{"binaryType":"blob","extensions":"","protocol":"","bufferedAmount":0,"readyState":3,"url":"ws://localhost:12345/","URL":"ws://localhost:12345/"},"type":"error"}
```

What does this error mean? And does it mean that we cannot use QWebSocketServer to support javascript websocket?

Comment: Not a lot to go on in that error. You should give a bit more information on your setup.

Comment: What kind of info do I need to provide??

Comment: I tried your code, and it worked fine for me. Where did you get the error from? Server side or in the browser? I'm using Qt 5.4.0beta and FF 33.

Comment: @Vin That's long time ago. I threw out websocket so the problem was kinda solved. I just want to know about the error... any clues?

Comment: Sorry but never saw the error or alike before. What I guess is that you might be using a Qt version that has a compatibility issue with the browser you used.